# Test apps on device while Apple Developer Portal down

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to test my app on my device using the Xcode Wildcard App ID. However, the Apple Developer Portal is down. When I try to run the app, I get `A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.`I've tried disabling code signing using methods I've found here and other places on the internet by editing the SDKSettings Plist file, and I get an error message `No code signature found.`

To make matters worse, the provisioning profile for my app expired during the outage, so I can't use that either. How can I test my app on a device before the portal is back up? I use cocos2d, so the framerate in the simulator is horrid.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about apple support.

Comment: It is about iOS device provisioning which is an integral part of iOS programming. There are many questions on this topic in SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you're SOL, unless you're willing to jailbreak...

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Testflight can solve your problem. You just need to release your .ipa